# series is divergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{2^k})$ diverges? I want to do this with the comparison test, but I don't find a divergent series.

 An other point I want to ask, if you can do this: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{2^k})=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}$? One of this series of the right hand side is convergent, therefore you don't have the undefined case $\infty -\infty$.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose the series converges. Then, since clearly $\;\sum\frac1{2^k}\;$ converges as it is a geometric series with quotient $\;\frac12\;,\;\;\left|\frac12\right|<1\;$ , then we'd get that also

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{2^k}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2^k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k\;\;\;\;\;\text{converges}$$

which is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

For $k$ large enough, $\frac1k - \frac1{2^k} \ge \frac1{2k}$ ($\equiv k \le 2^{k-1}$) and you can use your comparison test.

Also you cannot really write this equality of yours because $\sum^{\infty}_1 \frac1k$ does not exist (or "is $\infty$").

Comment: But it is true that if $a_n\to\infty$ and $b_n\to x\in\Bbb R$ then $a_n+b_n\to\infty$.

Comment: yes of course...

Comment: Thank you. How can I prove this inequality $\frac{1}{2k}\le \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{2^k}$ for natural k large enough?

Comment: Either you know that $2^k \gg k$ and it's obvious, or you can prove that $k \le 2^{k-1}$ by induction on $k$

Answer (score 0):

With *equivalents*  is often easier. It works for absolute convergence (tis series has positive terms):
$$\frac1k-\frac1{2^k}\sim_{\infty} \frac1k$$
and you know the harmonic series diverges.